# DirectShow.Net no combination of filters but fine in GSpot

Tags: c#, .net, video, directshow, directshow.net

I'm trying to use the DirectShot.Net wrapper from "http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/" to extract frames from a number of video files.

Whenever I run the DxScan sample app. I get a "No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection." This happens for WMV files, MP4 files, AVI files. Any media I point at the sample app.

If I open any of the videos using the GSpot codec tool and ask it to render the graph, it does so without problem. So the machine is definitely capable of playing the content.

I'm on Win 7 64 bit. The same error is thrown targeting x64, x86 or Auto. Including running Visual Studio as an Administrator.

I've modified the sample code to try and find the correct pin containing the video media type as suggested by Romain R below.

I'm using:

```
            IEnumPins epins;
            capFilter.EnumPins(out epins);
            IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
            IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
            while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
            {
                PinInfo pinfo;
                pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
                IEnumMediaTypes mtypes;
                pins[0].EnumMediaTypes(out mtypes);
                AMMediaType[] types = new AMMediaType[1];
                while(mtypes.Next(1, types, new IntPtr()) == 0){
                    var majorType = types[0].majorType;
                    if (majorType == MediaType.Video)
                    {
                         //This is never reached
                    }
                }
            }
```

For MP4 files, it's never hitting the commented line above. However for WMV files, the demo will now run correctly.

Presumably, this is because it isn't finding an appropriate MP4 file filter. Which is obscure as the content will play fine in windows media player.

Is this a likely cause?

Answer (score 0):

`DxScan` sample is building a filter graph in an unreliable way, in particular is makes an assumption that the first pin it grabs from the source filter supplied for a media file is a video pin. It is not always the case. A better graph building approach should be working out fine. You might want to step through to find out at what line you have an error. Most likely, it is going to be connection of Sample Grabber Filter input pin.

UPD. Note that it might so happen that original filter has no input pins, it requires additional filters in between, so called parser/demultiplexer filters which convert streams into video frames and audio samples. DirectShow API offers `Render*` methods to assist in graph building in terms of suggesting required links of this chain and direct connection DxScan is doing might or might not work out.

That is, DxScan might be not the best sample to start from, MSDN samples/reference for native API are perhaps better for taking off the ground with DirectShow.

Your playground and primary research and API exploration tool should be GraphEdit from Windows SDK (GraphStudio, or [GraphStudioNext](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/) as alternate improved options), not a DirectShow.NET wrapper library sample.

> Which is obscure as the content will play fine in windows media player.

WMP does not use DirectShow for playback.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of how to detect the Video Pin in DShow.Net?

Comment: You iterate through pins, you enumerate media types on them. If the first media type enumerated has `majortype == MEDIATYPE_Video` then it is a video pin.

Comment: Using the code above, it doesn't appear to be returning any pins that have majortype MediaType.Video
Presumably I'm testing pins on the correct filter (the capture filter)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was only using the DS.Net package as I need to extract frames from MP4 files within a .Net app.
So getting down and dirty with the native DS API wasn't really on my todo list!